# Does not output data from the database on vps

Tags: php, mysql

Everything works on the local server. Transferring to a vps server, no errors, but no data output.
In MYSQL, the database was created and exported. Maybe I'm not filling this file correctly?

db.php

```
<?php

$dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
$dbname = "translatedb";
$username = "root";
$userpass = "(password that was specified when installing mysql on the server)";
$charset = "utf8";
$options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];

$data = [
    "engVal" => trim($_POST["engVal"]),
    "rusVal" => trim($_POST["rusVal"]),
];

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname = $dbname;charset=$charset", $username, $userpass, $options);

if (!empty(trim($_POST["engVal"])) && !empty(trim($_POST["rusVal"]))) {
    $query = "INSERT `translatedb`.`words` (engword,rusword) VALUES (:engVal, :rusVal)";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $statement->execute($data);
};
```

res.php

```
<?php
    require_once("db.php");

    $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM  `translatedb`.`words`');
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr class='translater-table_item'>
             <td>" . $row['engword'] . "</td>
             <td>" . $row['rusword'] . "</td>
    </tr>";

}

    ?>
```

Comment: _Note (not your problem)_ Your website should not be using `root` as its user account to the mysql database

Comment: You don't `echo` anything so you'll never see output. Do you mean there's another script where you run a `select` on this data an its not present? If so try adding an `else` on the `empty` conditional and in that conditional output https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php to see if it says it inserted the record

Comment: As this code just does and INSERT (no output generated) Did you look at your database using phpMyAdmin or simply use the `mysql` command line processor

Comment: _Small Note_ Closing an IF with a `}` does not need a semi colon as well

Comment: added a second file for complete understanding

Comment: What should I specify instead of root?

Comment: You should create a new user, and give it access to ONLY what is required for the web site.

Comment: Is that right?? Your `db.php` has an INSERT in it??